# Converting CSV with LineString into shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, convert, linestring

I have a CSV which I've imported into ArcGIS Desktop, and it contains a Linestring column.

How do I convert it into a shapefile?

Example of what one of the fields contain below:

```
[[51.53878768021, -0.01805397057],[51.53878865403, -0.01811160963],
 [51.5393377751, -0.01814543493],[51.53936448971, -0.0181298538],
 [51.54012998282, -0.01766397309],[51.54065187717, -0.0171509813],
 [51.54082063461, -0.01649470118],[51.54057432587, -0.01575552408],
 [51.54042543071, -0.01545916271],[51.54022213116, -0.01513632888],
 [51.53982939314, -0.01477847997],[51.54004741802, -0.01384606376],
 [51.54013064554, -0.01291951037],[51.54015613891, -0.01283187515],
 [51.54036833688, -0.01208716771],[51.54207215087, -0.00862388496],
 [51.54215106745, -0.00850506822],[51.54274424885, -0.00742639128],
 [51.54273732937, -0.00490291103],[51.54273994243, -0.00452783466],
 [51.54280308915, -0.00453949369],[51.54287669256, -0.00463722526],
 [51.54334224557, -0.00451590589],[51.54334224557, -0.00451590589],
 [51.54333154362, -0.00441542146],[51.54335580468, -0.00425572003],
 [51.54355300498, -0.00421824756],[51.54375094078, -0.00422400837],
 [51.54396660328, -0.00421457153],[51.54396586774, -0.00417133769]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [arcpy's Geometry() classes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm):

```
coords = [[51.53878768021, -0.01805397057],[51.53878865403, -0.01811160963],[51.5393377751, -0.01814543493],[51.53936448971, -0.0181298538],[51.54012998282, -0.01766397309],[51.54065187717, -0.0171509813],[51.54082063461, -0.01649470118],[51.54057432587, -0.01575552408],[51.54042543071, -0.01545916271],[51.54022213116, -0.01513632888],[51.53982939314, -0.01477847997],[51.54004741802, -0.01384606376],[51.54013064554, -0.01291951037],[51.54015613891, -0.01283187515],[51.54036833688, -0.01208716771],[51.54207215087, -0.00862388496],[51.54215106745, -0.00850506822],[51.54274424885, -0.00742639128],[51.54273732937, -0.00490291103],[51.54273994243, -0.00452783466],[51.54280308915, -0.00453949369],[51.54287669256, -0.00463722526],[51.54334224557, -0.00451590589],[51.54334224557, -0.00451590589],[51.54333154362, -0.00441542146],[51.54335580468, -0.00425572003],[51.54355300498, -0.00421824756],[51.54375094078, -0.00422400837],[51.54396660328, -0.00421457153],[51.54396586774, -0.00417133769]]

geom = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*c) for c in coords]))

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(geom, r'C:\example\some_shape.shp')
```

Comment: How does one include other fields contained in the csv (e.g. year, time, name, etc.) into the shapefile?

Comment: I would use an [InsertCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) in that case